# Is there a way to use const variables in the definitions of other constants?

Tags: c, constants

I would like to use some previously defined constants in the definition of a new constant, but my C compiler doesn't like it:

```
const int a = 1;
const int b = 2;
const int c = a;         // error: initializer element is not constant
const int sum = (a + b); // error: initializer element is not constant
```

Is there a way to define a constant using the values of other constants? If not, what is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I don't get an error or even a warning with gcc 4.3.3

Comment: I used gcc 3.4.5 for this test, and CodeWarrior 5.7.0 for the more complicated program that led me down this path

Comment: gcc 4.3.3 does give these errors. There are no errors if you compile it as C++, since it's valid there, but as plain C you get the mentioned errors.

Comment: Bummer. I could easily use a different version of gcc, but I'm stuck with CodeWarrior for the actual project. Thank you for the tips regarding newer versions of gcc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Const vars can't be defined as an expression.

```
#define A (1)
#define B (2)
#define C (A + B)

const int a = A;
const int b = B;
const int c = C;
```

Comment: #undef A #undef B #undef C

Comment: C++0x will have constexpr type specifier, that will allow to define constants using other variables.

Answer (score 7):

Use enums in preference to preprocessor macros for integral const values:

```
enum {
    A = 1,
    B = 2
};

const int a = A;
const int b = B;
const int c = A;        
const int sum = (A + B);
```

Works in C and C++.

Comment: wouldn't making the all vars "static const int" and such work as well?

Comment: Not for C, only for C++ - but in that case you don't need the 'static' just being a previously seen const int is enough to make the identifier useable as part of an initializer for a const (or array size).

Answer (score 2):

You can only assign a literal to a const variable, so that program is illegal.
I think you should go with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

Since the results are meant to be constant, I agree with Michael Burr that enums are the way to do it, but unless you need to pass pointers to constant integers around, I wouldn't use the 'variables' (is a constant really a variable?) but just the enums:

```
enum { a = 1 };
enum { b = 2 };
enum { c = a };
enum { sum = a + b };
```

Comment: I would agree, but I was a bit lazy and didn't want to get into the whole modifyable vs. non-modifyable lvalue thing. Another little wrinkle is that with enums you have less control over the types, which may matter in terms of overload selection (obviously a C++ issue only).  However, these 2 things are very much rare corner cases - 99.9% of the time using enums alone as the 'manifest constant' works great.  And you avoid pretty much all the problems inherent in preprocessor macros.